# How can I create a y = log10(x) plot in python in range x = 1 to 1000?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, logarithm

I'm trying to plot y = log10(x) - squareroot(x) in Jupyter notebook with x in range 1 to 1000, any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to plot anything else?

Comment: you need to create the x and y values preferably using numpy and then use matplotlib to plot the x and y cords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [i for i in range(1,1001)]
y = [math.log10(i)-math.sqrt(i) for i in x]
plt.plot(x,y)
```